# How to mix titling and mdframed packages

Tags: mdframed, titling

Through a tip on this site, I have used package `mdframed` to get a nice rounded box. But I would like to include it with the `titling` package.

The following minimum example shows `mdframed` working correctly later in the document. It also shows `titling` working, as the `\thedate` and `\thetitle` are available after `\maketitle`, which is one of its helpful features. And I've included the `flushright` environment which works with `titling`. But the `mdframed` environment causes errors.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\title{My document's title}
\author{Jonathan Clark}
\date{10 May 2014}

% \pretitle{\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]\LARGE\bfseries}  % doesn't work
\pretitle{\LARGE\bfseries}    % but without mdframed it works
\posttitle{}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\scshape}
\postauthor{\end{flushright}}
\predate{\large}
% \postdate{\end{mdframed}}   % doesn't work
\postdate{\end{mdframed}}     % but without mdframed it worsk

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
Date: \thedate. Title: \thetitle.
\end{mdframed}

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

I believe I'm running the latest version of all packages via TeX Live on OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suuppose it's something like the following you want. I used the `etoolbox` package, and more specifically, `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` towrap `\maketitle` into the `mdframed` environment:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\title{My document's title}
\author{Jonathan Clark}
\date{10 May 2014}

\pretitle{\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\scshape}
\postauthor{\end{flushright}}
\predate{\large}
\postdate{}
\pretocmd{\maketitle}{\mdfsetup{roundcorner = 10pt,linewidth = 2pt, linecolor = Red3}\begin{mdframed}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\maketitle}{\end{mdframed}\bigskip}{}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; that looks a good answer.But any idea why the mdframed environment seems to be acting in a special way?

Comment: I think (not sure, though) it is  rather `maketitle` that acts in a special way.